# nginx не отдаёт статические файлы

Tags: nginx

Есть фронт написанный на vue. Nginx проксирует трафик с основного домена на него. Захотел поднять еще wordpress рядом. По урлу `xxx.ru/wordpress/`

```
location /wordpress/ 
{  
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Php-файлы открываются, а js,css и пр -нет

Пробую вот так. Ни в какую

```
location ~ ^/wordpress/(libs/|img/|js/|css/) 
{
     root /var/www/wordpress;
     access_log off;
     expires max;
}
```

Update. Вот так работает админка, но когда перехожу на xxx.ru/wordpress/index.php - редиректит на xxx.ru

```
 location /wordpress/ 
{

  alias /var/www/wordpress/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно значит не открываются? Что написано в логе ошибок?

Comment: 404 not found для css-js, а для пхп всё норм

Comment: @andreymal исправил

Comment: А в логе ошибок-то что?

Comment: Не тестируйте конфиг в браузере - кэш браузера не даст нормальной картины. Смотрите в сторону консольных утилит, либо используйте чистый браузер с режимом инкогнито. `wordpress` знает что он должен работать только на ссылке `/wordpress/`?